# ORMlite QueryBuilder Where A and B and C and (D or E or F)

Tags: android, query-builder, ormlite

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm not groking something about how to use the `or()` function on the Where statement of the QueryBuilder in ORMlite.

I have a query and I want it to be:

`where A and B and C and (D or E or F)`

but what the code is generating is:

`where (A and B and C and D) or E or F`

Not only is `D` getting included with the `and` clauses, but `E` and `F` are ungrouped meaning that ANY row that matches `E` will be returned but I need `A`, `B`, and `C` as requirements on all rows.

I've looked at the ORMlite example code and descriptions of the `or()` function, but they all seem to focus on an `(A and B) or (C and D)` scenario which isn't what I'm trying to do. I've tried to figure out how the code should work for my situation, but it is REALLY wrong so I don't know what concept I'm missing in how I should be using the `or()` function.

Any help?

```
protected void addWhereClauses(Where<Sheep, Integer> whereClause) throws SQLException {

    whereClause
            .eq("owner_id", this.owner.getId()) // A
            .and()
            .isNull("markedfordeletiondate") // B
            .and()
            .eq("isownedbyme", this.currentlyShowingSheepMine); // C


    String filterstring = getFilterString();
    if (filterstring != null) {
        filterstring = "%"+filterstring+"%";
        whereClause.and()
                .or(
                    whereClause.like("name", filterstring), // D
                    whereClause.like("tag", filterstring), // E
                    whereClause.like("scrapietag", filterstring) // F
                )
        ;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I know what the generated query looks like because I'm grabbing it and logging it to the console:

```
String sql = queryBuilder.prepareStatementString();
Log.d("BFLF", "sql: "+sql);
```

Comment: How do you know it's generating that? Purely based on the results?

Comment: I'm having the query builder spit out the raw SQL so I can see it for debugging purposes. I updated my post above with the code I used to log the sql statement.

Comment: If the or()  method takes many arguments, I personally don't see what's wrong with what you have. Try making a bug report on ormlite site? Would it be possible to switch to another ORM solution if this is, in fact, a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured out a way to make it work, but I'm not sure this is how I'm supposed to do it "properly." Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

The first change was that I captured the initial ABC clauses and passed those back into another `and()` clause along with an `or()` clause that had DEF in it.

```
protected void addWhereClauses(QueryBuilder<Sheep, Integer> queryBuilder, Where<Sheep, Integer> whereClause) throws SQLException {

    Where<Sheep, Integer> mainClause = whereClause
            .isNull("markedfordeletiondate")
            .and()
            .eq("isownedbyme", this.currentlyShowingSheepMine);


    String filterstring = getFilterString();
    if (filterstring != null) {
        String likestring = "%"+filterstring+"%";

        whereClause.and(
            mainClause,
            whereClause.or(
                    whereClause.like("name", likestring), // D
                    whereClause.like("tag", likestring), // E
                    whereClause.like("scrapietag", likestring) // F
            )
        );

    }
}
```